# Blazor / Entity Framework - Update parent when child collection is added to

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using a `Blazor` server side app with `Entity Framework`.

I have a parent entity `Booking` with a child collection of `Tours`. I have a page where I add tours to Booking's `Tours` *collection*.

```
public class Booking
{
   IEnumerable<Tours> Tours { get; set; }
}
```

I have a main parent booking component, which is just a shell for the booking sub-components, like Tours. I pass the child collection to the child component like so on the booking page:

```
<Tours Tours="Booking.Tours" />

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Booking = await BookingService.GetBooking(reference);
    }
}
```

However I find that, when I add a **Tour**, the page does not update with the newly added Tour unless I make a call to fetch the Booking with its children again.

```
private async Task addTour(TourState state)
{
    var newBookingTour = new BookingTour();

     var newTour = await BookingTourService.CreateBookingTour(newBookingTour);        

     // UI ONLY UPDATES WHEN I DO THIS

     Booking = await BookingService.GetBooking();
}
```

Here is the generic `method` I use to save entities to the `DB`:

```
public async Task<TEntity> Upsert(TEntity item)
{
    var entity = this.Context.Update(item);
    await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity.Entity;
}
```

Should I really be making a call to the `DB` again? Surely `Entity Framework` should pick up the newly added entity and feed it through to the `UI`? I feel I'm missing something here!

Any help appreciated as I'm new to both `EF` and `Blazor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I really be making a call to the DB again?

**No, you should not.**

> Surely Entity Framework should pick up the newly added entity

**Yes it does**

> and feed it through to the UI?

**No it wont, you have to**

You just have to update your model, you dont have to fetch it from the database as you already have a reference of the new item.

Assuming your service returns the entity:

```
private async Task addTour(TourState state)
{
   var newBookingTour = new BookingTour();

   var newTour = await BookingTourService.CreateBookingTour(newBookingTour);        


   Booking = ExistingBookig.Tours.Add(newTour);
}
```

Comment: of course! thank you, that's what I was missing. all working now. and that's clearly why they recommend using `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable` for child collections, the latter involves `ToList()`ing for all CRUD operations!